# Pumping Lemma,regular languages

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma, discrete-mathematics

Lets say that we have the  language L = { $a^n$$b^m$$c^{m+n}$ $|$ $m$,$n$ $>=0$ }
What is the way that i should  follow to prove

that the language is not regular?

- Assume that the language is regular.
- So,there is a string $w\in L$  such that $w = xyz$ , $|xy|\leq n, y\neqε  $, **n is the pumping length**

Lets say that the string that i choose( w string)  is $w = a^nb^mc^{m+n}$

Is this choice correct ?
Can someone explain me the best choice of $y$ ?

Should be $y = a^{n-r} $  and $x = a^n $ ?  Because  of $|xy|\leq n$ ?

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pumping Lemma for regular languages (by Wikipedia):**
Let $\displaystyle L$ be a regular language. Then there exists an integer $\displaystyle p\geq 1$ depending only on $\displaystyle $ such that every string $\displaystyle w$ in $\displaystyle L$ of length at least $\displaystyle p$ ($\displaystyle p$ is called the "pumping length") can be written as $\displaystyle w=xyz$ (i.e., $\displaystyle w$ can be divided into three substrings), satisfying the following conditions:

1. $\displaystyle |y|\geq 1$
2. $\displaystyle |xy|\leq p$
3. $\displaystyle (\forall k\geq 0)(xy^{k}z\in L)$

**Task**
The given Language is $L = \{a^nb^mc^{n+m}|m,n\geq 0\}$. We want to show that L is not regular through proof by contradiction using the pumping lemma.

First we assume that $L$ is regular as you wrote. This implies the existence of the pumping length $p$. You called the pumping length $n$ which might lead to confusion cause $n$ appears in the definition of the language; so I called it $p$. Since we make a proof by contradiction we need to choose a word $|w| \geq p, w\in L$ and show for **every possible partition** into $w = xyz, |xy|\leq p, |y|\geq 1$ that there is a $k$ such that $xy^kz\notin L$.

Now what $w$ could you choose? I think $a^pb^pc^{2p}$ is a good choice.
Because $w = xyz = a^pb^pc^{2p}, |xy|\leq p, |y| \geq 1$ implies that $x = a^{i}, y = a^j, i+j \leq p, j\geq1$ thus $xy^pz \notin L$ because the the string would look like $a^{i+p\cdot j}b^pc^{2\cdot p}$ and $i+p\cdot j + p \neq 2p$, so the property of the language is violated. That's how proof using the pumping lemma usually looks like.

Comment: So, you choose the word $a^pb^pc^2p$ because the sum of the powers of a,b must be on the power of c. After this, cause of $|xy| < p$  , x and y must contain only a's  and not b's or c's
So the $z$ part of the word is something like -> $z = a^{p -i -j}b^pc^{2p}$ ?

Comment: yes exactly. the word $w$ you choose must be in the language $w\in L$. and your equation for $z$ is right.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation!

Comment: This works, but a trifle easier is to pump $a^pc^p$.

Comment: right i didn't  notice that..